# How to distinguish one press with hold down key?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

There is a push button, I read with a digital pin ,

e.g. once this button is pressed ,  I want pin number D9 to be HIGH

If I hold this button long , I want D9 pin will never be HIGH, pin D10 will be HIGH

I couldn't fix this problem, how should I solve this problem

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: any own ideas? did you do any of  the Arduino button tutorials? It should be pretty clear what to do if you spent any time on learning the basics. are you familiar with millis()?

Comment: Pin D10 should not be related to your question. You are programming C++ with some arduino specific functions, and can define any variables you want, to distinguish different states (short / long press etc.)